# Python condition if/else invalid syntax

Tags: python

**Hi, can you help me with the following error? I know it sounds very stupid.
When doing an if / else conditional, I get a syntax error.
Would appreciate your help.**

```
 def request(self, email, password):
   session = requests.session()
   login_page = session.get(login_url)
   login_soup = BeautifulSoup(login_page.text,'html5lib' )
   e = login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})
   csrftok = e['value']
   session.post(login_url,data={'login_form[name]': user,'login_form[password]': passw,'login_form[redirect_url]': '/','login_form[_token]': csrftok})
   membership = session.get(member_url).text()
   if "Free" in membership:
       output().screen(email, password, case = "Free")
       else:
           output().screen(email, password, case = "Premium")
   else:
       output().screen(email, password, case = "Not Working")
```

Comment: You have `else` without `if`.

Comment: One `if`, two `else`?

Comment: It looks like you'll need to learn about `elif` to achieve the behaviour you're interested in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line here...

```
if "Free" in membership:
    output().screen(email, password, case = "Free")
    else:  # <----- Problematic line
        output().screen(email, password, case = "Premium")
else:
    output().screen(email, password, case = "Not Working")
```

has no corresponding `if` statement. You need another `if` statement, otherwise remove that line.

Comment: I guess what the OP is trying to do is an "else if", you may include an example to show how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do `if` `elif` `else`

```
if "Free" in membership:
   output().screen(email, password, case="Free")
elif "Premium" in membership:
   output().screen(email, password, case="Premium")
else:
   output().screen(email, password, case="Not Working")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python it is really important to respect indentation and to have a well organized code.
As you have an `else` statement without an `if`
And for {{else if}} you can use `elif`
So you have to follow the following pattern:

```
if c:
   code
elif c1:
   code1
else:
   code2
```

so your code has to be like this:

```
 def request(self, email, password):
   session = requests.session()
   login_page = session.get(login_url)
   login_soup = BeautifulSoup(login_page.text,'html5lib' )
   e = login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})
   csrftok = e['value']
   session.post(login_url,data={'login_form[name]': user,'login_form[password]': passw,'login_form[redirect_url]': '/','login_form[_token]': csrftok})
   membership = session.get(member_url).text()
   if "Free" in membership:
       if <<condition here>>:
           output().screen(email, password, case = "Free")
       else:
           output().screen(email, password, case = "Premium")
   else:
       output().screen(email, password, case = "Not Working")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Free" in membership:
   output().screen(email, password, case = "Free")
>>>else:
       output().screen(email, password, case = "Premium")
else:
       output().screen(email, password, case = "Not Working")
```

1. Indentation
2. There is a stray 'else'